# Generate records out of nested structure and convert to CSV

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have the following JSON that I want to convert to CSV. It is an array of arrays, which contains an object and an array of objects.

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "DATA": [
        {
          "V": 192.1,
          "Q": 0,
          "T": "2020-06-12T16:52:10.000Z"
        },
        {
          "V": 175.2,
          "Q": 0,
          "T": "2020-06-12T16:53:50.000Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "DATA": [
        {
          "V": 176,
          "Q": 0,
          "T": "2020-06-12T16:53:25.000Z"
        },
        {
          "V": 122.8,
          "Q": 0,
          "T": "2020-06-12T16:53:30.000Z"
        },
        {
          "V": 122.01,
          "Q": 0,
          "T": "2020-06-12T16:55:35.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

The desired is the following:

```
A,192.1,0,2020-06-12T16:52:10.000Z
A,175.2,0,2020-06-12T16:53:50.000Z
B,176,0,2020-06-12T16:53:25.000Z
B,122.8,0,2020-06-12T16:53:30.000Z
B,122.01,0,2020-06-12T16:55:35.000Z
```

My output is generating the product of `name` and `DATA`, which is not what I need.

Comment: Please post your research attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.[][] | [.name] + (.DATA[] | [.V,.Q,.T]) | @csv
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/FueYg4n558)</sup>

If the keys in elements of `DATA` are always in the same order, you can use the following instead.

```
.[][] | [.name] + (.DATA[] | map(.)) | @csv
```

To get a valid CSV output, you need to invoke JQ with -r/--raw-output option.